# Paket: what is the point of the framework restrictions?

Tags: c#, .net, f#, paket, target-framework

The [`paket.dependencies`](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/dependencies-file.html) page of the Paket documentation describes the purpose of the framework restriction field `framework` very briefly, and I still don't understand what it does.

Apparently, the specified frameworks will cause Paket to download and reference only those packages/libraries/APIs -- I'm not sure of the right terminology -- which fall within at least one of the named frameworks.

So what is the point of the `TargetFramework` fields of the projects, then? I had thought that that's what they were supposed to do. How does Paket's `framework` specification interact with the solution's projects' `TargetFramework` specifications?

Comment: I think it only says "download", not "reference"? A single NuGet package may include multiple binaries, for different targets. These are all downloaded together, and (when using NuGet/`dotnet`) are all stored next to each other on disk, regardless of which ones are actually referenced. I think this is telling Paket not to bother extracting and storing any binaries which aren't for your selected targets. Also see `framework: auto-detect
` in the section below -- you can tell Paket "only bother downloading and storing the binaries which my project is going to reference"

Comment: @canton7 Oh I see, thanks. So it just limits what is downloaded to your `~/.nuget/packages` directory? But why would you want a per-solution specification for that? Shouldn't it be a global Paket configuration setting? Yes, that `framework: auto-detect` makes more sense to me.

Comment: I don't know: I don't use Paket. I'm combining my reading of that doc with my knowledge of NuGet. [This doc](https://fsprojects.github.io/Paket/paket-folder.html) says that Paket downloads stuff to a `.paket` directory in the root of your repository, so it's not user-wide. My guess is that the auto-detection is relatively recent (with SDK-style csprojs perhaps?) and/or fails in some circumstances. Which frameworks your project targets definitely isn't a global setting: that's a per-project setting.